# Wordpress RSS feed with custom description?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, atom-feed

Is there a nice and simple way to add a filter to the wordpress RSS feed functions?
I want to insert some custom text into the `<description>` tag of my RSS2 feed and the `<summary>` tag of my Atom feed. Is there any easy way to do that?

I don't have templates for my feeds in my theme (like wp-rss2.php or wp-atom.php). I've just added the normal

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Atom Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
```

to my `<head>`

Any idea how I can influence the description and summary of my feeds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several options depending on your comfort/experience level:

- Install a plugin like [Feed Wrangler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-wrangler/) or [Ozh Better Feed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ozh-better-feed/)
- Use a 3rd party service like [Feedburner](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_FeedBurner)
- Hook into the feed using [various PHP functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds)
- Or edit the [feed output](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content_rss)