# How to customize the Word Press RSS feed description tag, without touching the php code?

Tags: wordpress, rss, rss2

[Wordpress RSS feed with custom description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050073/wordpress-rss-feed-with-custom-description)

I found the post from 7 years ago, however the accepted answer is outdated because the plugins are no longer compatible with the latest version of Word Press.

I am not familiar with php or the Word Press functions, so a plugin is what I am looking for.

I am trying to reduce the size of the post excerpt in the description tag and edit the "Continue Reading " link at the end of the description tag.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Custom Simple Rss ? https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-simple-rss/

Comment: Hello I tried it, but I was unable to change the description tag with that plugin.